# Use ST functions in GeoDjango Project

Tags: python, geodjango

I have a Geo-Django project in which i am using postgres as database. I have a table with geometry column. I am filtering data and getting results which is working fine.

Problem is I want the geometry results in text form so i am trying to use ST_AsText in it. The Issue is I tried passing this function multiple ways and using annotations as well but I am not able to do that due to multiple errors.

As suggestion or successful implementation of applying ST_ functions would help me.

```
pointsArr = ScrapedArea.objects.filter(geom__intersects=poly).values('geom', 'url')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert it to a geosgeometry object before passing it into the query: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/gis/geos/

Then, use the annotate method with it:

```py
>>> from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Length
>>> Track.objects.annotate(length=Length('line')).filter(length__gt=100)
```

https://django.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/contrib/gis/functions.html

Comment: No its not about the geometry being sent in input. Its about the one coming as a result from query.

Comment: Can you add an example of what you have attempted?

Comment: Added an example.